# ¿Cómo lanzo un script de shell cuando se realice un UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, trigger

Tengo una base de datos en mysql en la que necesito saber qué se modifico. Para ello, quiero mandarlo por shell a un script Python cuando se ejecute el UPDATE.

No sé mucho de los triggers ni nada de eso, solo algo basico de base de datos. Mi idea es ver si se puede usar sys_exec o algo que me ejecute este comando:

```
python enviar.py '1-INICIADO'
```

Id siendo el id de la fila y estado uno de los valores.

De ultima si eso no es capaz de hacerlo una base de datos, armare un script que esté constantemente chequeando los estados, que es algo que me saca del apuro pero no me gusta.

```
ID|ESTADO
1  | INICIADO
2  | STOP
3  | DESHABIITADO
4  | STOP
5  | INICIADO
```